# nginx - reverse proxy for large number of hosts

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, multi-tenant

We have a port based multi tenancy. Right now we have a separate file in sites-available directory for each tenant. This is becoming cumbersome to manage as the number of tenants grow. Is there a better alternative to this? Each tenant has a separate sub domain.

We can maintain sub domain - port mapping either in db, or in redis. Would it be a better idea to keep it in redis and dynamically route it?

```
  server {  
    server_name abc.mydomain.com;   
    location /{ proxy_pass http://localhost:7000;   
    proxy_http_version 1.1;   
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;   
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';   
    proxy_set_header Host $host;   
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;   
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;   
    } 
  }
```

Comment: @AlexeyTen   `server {
        server_name abc.mydomain.com;
  location /{
           proxy_pass http://localhost:7000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
           }
        }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up creating a template config file, and having a script generating the actual config files. In my case, it is a nodejs script that will loop through the projects directory, and create a config file for each directory in a config folder. This config folder location is "include"d in the nginx.conf.

Answer (score 0):

How about use include ?

In my case, i'm using include file

```
  server {
   include /etc/nginx/hosts/music.wper.kr;
  }
  server {
   include /etc/nginx/hosts/cet.wper.kr;
  }
```

you can copy & paste each host.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This also involves creating a separate file for each sub domain. In my case the only varialbles are the sub domain and the port, so I am wondering if it is possible to have a more automated way of doing this.